# Firebase Cloud Functions Shell not executing write operations on realtime database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Since a few days I am not able to test cloud functions locally anymore, as all write functions are not executed and nothing is returned, consequently the function hangs and eventually stops with a timeout.

Example function:

```
import { database as dbEvent } from "firebase-functions";

export default dbEvent.ref("/tariffs/removeHistory").onCreate((event: any) => {
  console.log("START");
  const bikesHistoryRef = event.data.adminRef.parent.parent.child("bikesHistory");
  return bikesHistoryRef.set(null).then((res) => console.log("Delete done", res));
});
```

Result:

```
firebase > removeBikeHistory("test")
'Successfully invoked function.'
firebase > info: User function triggered, starting execution
info: START

firebase > 
firebase > info: Execution took 61023 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'
info: Execution took 49694 ms, finished with status: 'crash'
```

Any suggestion what is wrong? This happens with all my cloud functions, and when I deploy them it works.

I have tried with:

```
firebase-admin@5.5.1
firebase-functions@0.7.3
firebase-tools@3.15.4 (-g)
```

and

```
firebase-admin@5.6.0
firebase-functions@0.7.5
firebase-tools@3.16.0 (-g)
```

EDIT:

After enabling logging I get the following errors:

```
info: 0: onDisconnectEvents 
info: p:0: Making a connection attempt 
info: p:0: Failed to get token: Error: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token: invalid_grant (Bad Request)". There are two likely causes: (1) your server time is not properly synced or (2) your certificate key file has been revoked. To solve (1), re-sync the time on your server. To solve (2), make sure the key ID for your key file is still present at https://console.firebase.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/project. If not, generate a new key file at https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk. 
p:0: data client disconnected 
info: p:0: Trying to reconnect in 1283.8299240003184ms 
0: onDisconnectEvents
```

I have actually seen this error when I installed an older firebase-function/admin version, but thought it got fixed by installing the newer version. How can I fix it?

Comment: What happens if you enable logging before doing anything with the database?  `admin.database.enableLogging(true)`  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database#.enableLogging

Comment: Also, do you use the `gcloud` command line at all?

Comment: I don't use gcloud CLI, only firebase CLI. Should I use gcloud? I have now enabled logging, see EDIT in my post above.

Comment: Thanks Doug, thanks to your logging hint I found the solution, see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution in this bug report:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/135

I have deleted the following file, now my cloud functions work locally again:

```
rm ~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json
```

Comment: If you do have gcloud, you can also run `gcloud auth application-default login` to reset this.